# sorting objects vertically with margin space between them

Tags: javascript, sorting, phaser-framework

I'm drawing a simple panel (using `Phaser.Graphics`) which will contain a list of pre-defined amount of list-entries (also drawn using`Phaser.Graphics`). 
The size of each list-entry is dynamically calculated to fit the panel size.

Width of my list-entries are (+-) same as panel's width.
To get the height, I'm dividing panel's height by the number of list-entries and their margins size.

The result is almost accurate, but I'm still getting either some extra or missing some pixels below the last list-entry. So I suppose my calculation isn't correct or missing something ...

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 300, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', {
  create: create
});

var panel = null;
var listItems = 3
var listEntries = [];

function create() {
  createPanel(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, game.world.width - 50, game.world.height - 100);
  createList(panel);
}

function createPanel(x, y, width, height) {
  panel = game.make.graphics(0, 0);
  panel.position.x = x - (width / 2);
  panel.position.y = y - (height / 2);
  panel.lineStyle(2, 0x999999, 0.4);
  panel.beginFill(0x0d1a26, 0.6);
  panel.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
  panel.endFill();
  game.world.add(panel)
}

function createList(parent) {
  let child;
  let margin = 5;
  let width = parent.width - parent.lineWidth; //// - borders width? ////
  let height = (parent.height - ( listItems * (margin * 2) )) / listItems;
  let centerX = ((parent.width - width) / 2) - 1; /// - left-border width? ///

  let prev_pos = 0;
  for (let e = 0, e_l = listItems; e < e_l; e++) {

    listEntries[e] = this.game.make.graphics(0, 0);
    createListEntry(listEntries[e], width, height);
    child = parent.addChild(listEntries[e]);

    child.position.x += centerX;
    if (e > 0) {
      child.position.y += prev_pos + (margin * 2);
    } else {
      child.position.y += prev_pos + margin;
    }
    prev_pos = child.position.y + height;
    console.log(child.position.y)
  }
}

function createListEntry(entry, width, height) {
  entry.clear();
  entry.lineStyle(2, 0x999999, 0.5);
  entry.beginFill(0x0d1a26, 0.7);
  entry.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
  entry.endFill();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    canvas {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note that your HTML is also invalid. You should put that `script` element within your `body`.

Answer (score 1):

### Integers for pixels.

From memory Phaser (the version that was about 2-3 years ago) would use an optimisation in javascript of converting all rendering coordinates to integers.

If you give it doubles it will floor them (or round I can't remember which). As you have a fraction that you carry through your position `prev_pos` is not matching the actual placement of the panels.

The easy fix is to only give Phaser integers. In this case round up with `prev_pos = Math.ceil(child.position.y + height);`

#### Fixed?

Your code with the minor change commented.

```js
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 300, Phaser.AUTO, 'phaser-example', {
  create: create
});

var panel = null;
var listItems = 3
var listEntries = [];

function create() {
  createPanel(game.world.centerX, game.world.centerY, game.world.width - 50, game.world.height - 100);
  createList(panel);
}

function createPanel(x, y, width, height) {
  panel = game.make.graphics(0, 0);
  panel.position.x = x - (width / 2);
  panel.position.y = y - (height / 2);
  panel.lineStyle(2, 0x999999, 0.4);
  panel.beginFill(0x0d1a26, 0.6);
  panel.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
  panel.endFill();
  game.world.add(panel)
}

function createList(parent) {
  let child;
  let margin = 5;
  let width = parent.width - parent.lineWidth; //// - borders width? ////
  let height = (parent.height - ( listItems * (margin * 2) )) / listItems;
  let centerX = ((parent.width - width) / 2) - 1; /// - left-border width? ///

  let prev_pos = 0;
  for (let e = 0, e_l = listItems; e < e_l; e++) {

    listEntries[e] = this.game.make.graphics(0, 0);
    createListEntry(listEntries[e], width, height);
    child = parent.addChild(listEntries[e]);

    child.position.x += centerX;
    if (e > 0) {
      child.position.y += prev_pos + (margin * 2);
    } else {
      child.position.y += prev_pos + margin;
    }
    // The new expression               
    prev_pos = Math.ceil(child.position.y + height);
    //.........^^^^^^^^^^.........................^
    // the added code.
  }
}

function createListEntry(entry, width, height) {
  entry.clear();
  entry.lineStyle(2, 0x999999, 0.5);
  entry.beginFill(0x0d1a26, 0.7);
  entry.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
  entry.endFill();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.6.2/phaser.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    canvas {
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```